# How can you disable the browser to view ASP source code from client user side?

Tags: security, asp-classic

How can you disable the browser to view ASP source code from client user side?
any possibilities or some scripts to code. If only ASP code is hidden that would be fine. if some encapsulation is possible also fine to me.......

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ASP source code can't be viewed in the browser, unless it's not marked as an ASP block of code.